# Ruby: What is a simple way of searching for certain criteria in an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, criteria

I have an array which I want to make sure all the numbers are between 1 and 6. Here is my array:

```
guess = [2, 5, 6, 8]
```

Or something like that. The user inputs the sequence. Anyway, I want a way to check it, and if the numbers aren't all between 1 and 6, it won't break out of the loop. And also could it please be simple!

Answer (score 7):

```
guess.all?{|i| (1..6).include?(i)}
```

Comment: guess.all?{|i| (1..6).include?(i)} == true

Answer (score 0):

```
guess.count{|i| i.between?(1,6)} == guess.size
```